# SQL - Get two users' names

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get names of users from a voting table, I can't quite figure out how to get both the voter's name and the votee's name.

Simplified Votes Table

```
ID   voteeID    voterID
1    1          2
2    1          3
3    1          4
4    2          1
5    2          3
6    2          4
```

Simplified User Info Table

```
ID   username
1    Bob
2    Sam
3    Ed
4    Mark
```

Where I'm at:

```
SELECT votes.voteeID, votes.voterID, userinfo.username
FROM votes
JOIN ???
```

I was playing around with the join, but I'm kind of stuck. If I join on the votee's id to the userinfo id, how would I also get the voter's name or vice versa?

Database: MySQL 5

Any help or even a hint would be wonderful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this one,

```
SELECT  b.`username` as Votee_Name,
        c.`username` as Voter_Name
FROM    Votes a
            INNER JOIN UserInfo b
                ON a.voteeID = b.Id
            INNER JOIN UserInfo c
                on a.voterID = c.id
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b102/3)

Comment: Never knew you could inner join the table twice... definitely gotta get better with SQL.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
SELECT  v.ID,
        v.voteeID,
        u1.username Votee,
        v.voterID,
        u2.username Voter
FROM    Votes v INNER JOIN
        User u1     ON  v.voteeID = u1.ID INNER JOIN
        User u2     ON  v.voterID = u2.ID
```

Comment: Just a quickie. Would you not need as before Votee and Voter?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it is not required.

Comment: From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html *The AS keyword is optional when aliasing a select_expr with an identifier.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to take `INNER JOIN` twice to get usernames for both `votee` and `voter`:

```
SELECT a.voteeID, a.voterID,
       b.username AS votee_name, c.username AS voter_name
FROM votes a
     INNER JOIN userinfo b
         ON a.voteeID = b.ID
     INNER JOIN userinfo c
         ON a.voterID = c.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT V.ID as ID B.username as Votee_Name, C.username as Voter_Name
  FROM Votes V
 INNER JOIN UserInfo B ON V.voteeID = B.Id
 INNER JOIN UserInfo C on V.voterID = C.id;